# Oracle Cloud Ubuntu Instance has no public ip?

Tags: ubuntu, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I just sign up an oracle free tier account and create a Ubuntu instance. But it does no have a public ip.

```
Primary VNIC Information
Private IP Address:10.0.0.2
Internal FQDN:instance-20191003-0043...ShowCopy
Public IP Address:Unavailable
Subnet:Public Subnet
Network Security Groups:
None
```

I looked around and asked oracle customer service, but they said they have no support to Ubuntu :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Ubuntu Instances does not have a Public IP assigned. Upon creating your Instance on Configure Networking Section of Create Compute Instance Page choose "Assign a Public IP address" radio button (located at the bottom).

[image: screenshot of create instance dialog]

Comment: I searched everywhere, but could not find this secret radio button. When creating the ubuntu instance, there is a Networking tab, but with only 2 optional input fields, Private IP address and Hostname. No `Assign a Public IP address` is found.

Comment: Found it. Need to click network link to expand the options

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Has the question been answered? I attached a picture. So from the Menu >> Instances > Create Instance > at the bottom of the page you can see the "Assign a Public IP"

Comment: Yes, the question has been answered. By you! You can edit your previous answer to include this screenshot instead of writing a new answer altogether.